# Understanding Dilworth's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

One formulation of Dilworth's theorem(for finite partially ordered sets) states that :

> There exists an antichain A, and a partition of the order into a family P of chains, such that the number of chains in the partition equals the cardinality of A.

The above is an extract from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem) wiki page. However, I don't understand how the above statement is equivalent to the following formulation of the theorem.

> In any finite partially ordered set, the maximum number of elements in any antichain equals the minimum number of chains in any partition of the set into chains.

The wiki article does try to explain this. Here is their explanation:

> Dilworth's theorem states that there exists an antichain A, and a partition of the order into a family P of chains, such that the number of chains in the partition equals the cardinality of A. When this occurs, A must be the largest antichain in the order, for any antichain can have at most one element from each member of P. Similarly, P must be the smallest family of chains into which the order can be partitioned, for any partition into chains must have at least one chain per element of A.

I don't get why the statements "...for any antichain can have at most one element from each member of P" and "....for any partition into chains must have at least one chain per element of A" together imply the maximality of the antichain and the minimality of the number of chains.

Any help in understanding why these are equivalent formulations will be appreciated.

**Background:** I am mostly a problem solver. I am learning order theory because of its connections to Hall's marriage lemma and because it seems very interesting. I am **not** following any book, but am trying to learn some order theory online. So I am a total beginner in this area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this proof, actually two things are shown:

1) Max. Cardinality of an Antichain $\le$ Minimum Number of chains in partition

2) Max. Cardinality of an Antichain $\ge$ Minimum Number of chains in partition

If you have both oft these, equality follows.

One oft them is easy (which one?) and this is explained in the Wikipedia Article.
The other one is harder, but for this now it suffices to show the existence oft one Antichain and Partition with the same cardinality, then equality immediately follows, because you already have the other Inequality!
(this is the difficult part, have you already read this proof? But worry not, to answer your question we don't have to go into the details, the problems right now are concerned with the proof method)

Comment: Okay, let me try and see which one is obvious. Take the maximal antichain. Then each element of the antichain must belong to  a different chain. This implies that the max number of elements in an antichain is less than or equal to the minimum number of chains in the partition. Am I right?

Comment: If we show that (1) is true(which I think I have done in my previous comment), and assume that the first formulation of Dilworth is true, then the number of partitions must be minimal because if there was a smaller partition, then each element of the antichain cannot belong to exactly one chain because of the Pigeonhole Principle. Hence the number of partitions must be minimal. Is my proof right? And thanks for the help.

Comment: Wait, I am not sure where I am using (1) . Can you point it out to me?

Comment: You use 1 in the final step: If you have the first inequality, and show that the Minimum is acquired, then equality must hold

Comment: My question was why the two formulations of Dilworth are same i.e. why does the equality of the cardinality of the antichain and number of partitions imply maximality of A and minimality of number of chains. (1) shows that max A is smaller than or equal to min(partitions). Then showing that equality is achieved does not mean that whenever the number of antichains equals the number of partitions into chains,the cardinality of antichain is maximized and the cardinality of partitions is minimized. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, lets start again:
You have already shown in your first comment the first inequality: That the maximum cardinality of an antichain is less or eqaul than the minimum number of chains that partiation the set. (This is because one of the chains can't contain more than one element of the Antichain, because those weren't comparable)

Now suppose you have an Antichain and also a partition of the set in chains, and both have the same Cardinality.
Claim: The Antichain is maximal.
Proof: Suppose not. But the number of chains in the partition was an upper bound on the length. Contradiction.

Comment: Analogue: Claim: The cardinality of the partition is minimal.
Proof: Suppose you find a smaller partition, but the length of the antichain was a lower bound (this was (1)), contradiction.
Maybe you've noticed that we didn't really had to go into details about the entire Chain/Antichain-business. This is because all your questions were just about the proof method used, not really about the content of the theorem.

Comment: I have finally gotten it! Thanks a lot for your patience.