# How could we partition P(x) in to minimum number chains?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider p(x) as a partially ordered set

〈P(X), ⊆〉 (the power set of X ordered by inclusion relation, for arbitrary set X);

we wish to partition P(X) into chains while the number of partition be minimum.
Help me to find a algorithm to do that.

(A chain is a subset of a partially ordered set in which each pair of elements is comparable.

An antichain is a subset of a partially ordered set such that any two elements in the subset are incomparable.)

from Dilworth theorem we know that the minimum number of this partitioning is equal to the size of the maximum Anti-chain exist in 〈P(X), ⊆〉.

You can also see dilworth theorem in below link:

[Understanding Dilworth's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208735/understanding-dilworths-theorem)

Comment: See [Sperner’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner's_theorem): if $|X|=n$, the family of subsets of $X$ of cardinality $\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$ is a maximal antichain of largest possible cardinality, and that cardinality is $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you that was helpful ;)

Comment: You’re welcome.